# Network error: Software caused connection abort during copying on linux

Tags: linux

On my remote, I have a recursive directory 'dir'. I try to copy all the files in 'dir' into a folder in another location on the remote on Linux. It copies and an hour later or so on the terminal I get;

```
Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file

Network error: Software caused connection abort
```

This happens each time. I don`t know if it stopped after it copied everything or before. I compared the size of the two files using;

```
du -sh file_path
```

They are 71G and 70G.Does anyone know why this network error occurs, and how can I prevent it? I use mobaXterm, and although I didn`t watch every minute of it but I didn't see internet disconnection during the copying.
thanks

Comment: Try turning on the `Enable SSH keepalive` setting on mobaxterm.

Comment: I had no idea such an option exist, thank you very much, i just checked, it was unchecked in settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really help you on the disconnection issue, but if the problem still exists and/or annoys you, you could copy the files with the *nohup* command. This would keep the copy process alive even if you get disconnected.

To synchronize your source and destination directory using *rsync*, you could use

```
nohup rsync -av /path_to/source_directory/ /path_to/destination_directory &
```

This would copy all remaining files and directories (if any) from the source to the destination directory and would also make sure that no "partly" copied files are left in the destination directory.

Another possibility to check if both directories contain the same files is the use of *diff*:

```
# compare dirs and watch result in terminal
diff -r /path_to/source_directory /path_to/destination_directory
# compare dirs and write result to diff.log (disconnection failsafe)
nohup diff -r /path_to/source_directory /path_to/destination_directory > diff.log &
```

The second command would create a logfile *diff.log* of all files only existing in one of both directories as well as all files with differences (partly copied) and thus help you find out at which point the copy process was aborted.

Comment: I was searching how I could use rsync instead and got your answer, very helpful, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Make sure you add the trailing slash "/" to the source directory, otherwise you will copy your source directory as subdirectory to the destination dir. If you previously did a `cp -r /home/user/dir1 /tmp/dir2` you will need `rsync -av /home/user/dir1/ /tmp/dir2`.

Comment: Hi,  yes, I do put "/". Also  I have just tried 'diff -r command and saw the difference between two folders. Learned two things today from you, thank you!